# Trying to iterate over a JSON object in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to display a toggle checkbox for every JSON value I have. This is what the json object looks like for `element`

```
{
    "sourceIP": {
        "Primary": ["237.100.100.3", "238.0.4.8"],
        "Secondary": ["237.0.1.178", "237.1.1.91"]
    },
    "multicastIP": {
        "Primary": ["10.208.153.129", "238.0.4.8"],
        "Secondary": ["10.208.133.58", "238.0.4.8"]
    }
}
```

So I would like to iterate through element instead of hardcoding it like this:

```
const CustomToggle = ({ element}) => (
<List divided verticalAlign='middle'>
    <Segment textAlign='left' style={{paddingLeft: '7.5em'}}>
        <Checkbox
            toggle
            label={(JSON.stringify(element.sourceIP.Primary[0]))}
            value={(JSON.stringify(element.sourceIP.Primary[0]))}
        />
        <Checkbox
            toggle
            label={(JSON.stringify(element.sourceIP.Primary[1]))}
            value={(JSON.stringify(element.sourceIP.Primary[1]))}
        />
        <Checkbox
            toggle
            label={(JSON.stringify(element.sourceIP.Secondary[1]))}
            value={(JSON.stringify(element.sourceIP.Secondary[1]))}
        />
    </Segment>

</List>
```

);

I have been trying to forEach and .map but none of this seems to work. I don't want to have to hardcode every json value in `element`. How can I just iterate through my element JSON object?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string format.

Comment: Is the structure/shape of the element JSON object same every time?

Comment: Yes it is always the same object with same field names. The arrays are also static in Primary and Secondary. They always have 2 values [0] and [1]

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(element).reduce((a,c) => a.concat(...Object.values(element[c])),[])
```

> this transformed data gives array of ip adtresses. So, now you can iterate it

```
const CustomToggle = ({ element}) => {
  const elements = Object.keys(element).reduce((a,c) => a.concat(...Object.values(element[c])),[]); 
  return (
    <List divided verticalAlign='middle'> 
       <Segment textAlign='left' style={{paddingLeft: '7.5em'}}>
          {elements.map(ip => <Checkbox toggle label={ip} value={ip} />}
        </Segment> 
     </List>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, let me know if it helps :)

```js
const CustomToggle = ({ element }) => (
  <List divided verticalAlign="middle">
    <Segment textAlign="left" style={{ paddingLeft: "7.5em" }}>
      {Object.keys(element).map(key => {
        return [...element[key].Primary, ...element[key].Secondary].map(x => {
          <Checkbox toggle label={x} value={x} />;
        });
      })}
    </Segment>
  </List>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example do something like the snipped below:

```js
const List = ({ divided, rest }) => <div {...rest} />;
const Checkbox = ({ toggle, ...props }) => (
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" {...props} />
    <label>{props.label}</label>
  </div>
);
const Segment = (props) => <div {...props} />;

const CustomToggle = ({ element }) => (
  <div>
    {element.map((ip) => (
      <Checkbox toggle label={ip} value={ip} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

function App() {
  let result = `{
        "sourceIP": {
            "Primary": ["237.100.100.3", "238.0.4.8"],
            "Secondary": ["237.0.1.178", "237.1.1.91"]
        },
        "multicastIP": {
            "Primary": ["10.208.153.129", "238.0.4.8"],
            "Secondary": ["10.208.133.58", "238.0.4.8"]
        }
    }`;
  let data = JSON.parse(result);
  let ips = [];
  Object.keys(data).map((source) => {
    Object.keys(data[source]).map((type) => {
      ips.push(...data[source][type]);
    });
  });
  return <CustomToggle element={ips} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

So, you'll parse the data, then iterate over it to get the IPs and then pass those as a prop to the `CustomToggle`. The code above is just an example to get you going as I don't know what your `List`, `Checkbox` and `Segment` components look like.

The reasoning is that `CustomToggle` should not know or care what the data should look like, it just knows how to render a custom toggle based on some string that it receives, in this case the ip. You should however make sure that each `Checkbox` has a unique key.